# Why can't I hear audio in stereo when playing a stereo file with Agora SDK?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-implementation

When calling `startAudioMixing` or `playEffect` to play a stereo file, I keep encountering the issue of not being able to hear audio in stereo.